# Do I need onlyamsmath when using nag?

Tags: packages, nag

I already read questions about recommended packages, and they often have the advice for

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
```

and

```
\usepackage[all, warning]{onlyamsmath}
```

I use `nag` for quite some time now and am unsure if I still need `onlyamsmath`. My question: as far as I understand, `nag` already does everything and more that `onlyamsmath` is doing when it comes to math environments (warn about "bad" math environments), is this correct?

So, does `onlyamsmath` bring any further advantage if I already use `nag`? I don't need the error functionality of `onlyamsmath`, only the warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found some time to test this out. I tested everything that `onlyamsmath` mentioned in its documentation, assuming the documentation is complete. The following code:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrreprt}

%\usepackage[all, warning]{onlyamsmath}

\begin{document}

$$a = b$$

\begin{eqnarray}
  a = b
\label{eq:foo1}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray*}
  a = b
\label{eq:foo2}
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{displaymath}
  a = b
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Generates these warnings:

```
Package nag Warning: $$...$$ is obsolete.
(nag)                Use \[...\] et al. instead on input line 8.

Package nag Warning: Environment eqnarray is obsolete. 
(nag)                Use amsmath's align instead on input line 10.

Package nag Warning: Environment eqnarray is obsolete. 
(nag)                Use amsmath's align instead on input line 15.
```

And now commenting out `nag` and commenting in `onlyamsmath` produces these warnings:

```
Package onlyamsmath Warning: Environment $$ $$ used, please use 
(onlyamsmath)                only the environments provided by the amsmath 
(onlyamsmath)                package on input line 8.

Package onlyamsmath Warning: Environment eqnarray or eqnarray* used, please use 
(onlyamsmath)                only the environments provided by the amsmath 
(onlyamsmath)                package on input line 10.

Package onlyamsmath Warning: Environment eqnarray or eqnarray* used, please use 
(onlyamsmath)                only the environments provided by the amsmath 
(onlyamsmath)                package on input line 15.

Package onlyamsmath Warning: Environment displaymath used, please use 
(onlyamsmath)                only the environments provided by the amsmath 
(onlyamsmath)                package on input line 20.
```

If you use both at the same time, only `onlyamsmath` will complain about `$$...$$`, but `nag` will not. `eqnarray` will be warned about by both packages at the same time. `displaymath` is only complained about by `onlyamsmath` in all cases.

Conclusion: Yes, `onlyamsmath` does detect something that `nag` won't detect (`displaymath`).